# behavior of differentials under pullback via ramified maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A rather famous person said to me today something to the order of:

Given a ramified map of curves $f : X\rightarrow Y$ of degree $d$ (say, over $\mathbb{C}$), the sheaf of holomorphic differentials $\Omega^1_Y$ becomes $(\Omega^1_Y)^d$ on $X$, or something to that effect.

I can't seem to make sense of this statement. It seems to me that pullback of a differential 1-form on $Y$ also gives you a differential 1-form on $X$. In what sense is the above true?

(Of course at the time I didn't want to ask him to clarify for fear of embarrassing myself, but now I'm suffering the consequences...)

Comment: This makes sense locally, as for every non-ramification point of $x$ you can see $f$ in a neighborhood of $x$ as the formal inverse of a $d$-covering map. However, I don't know enough about this stuff to make the argument formal (or clearer). I would say that something like that will not be true globally, but I'm not sure.